# Alter Multiple column Name and Data Type in PostgreSQL in one query

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

**Description:** I want to change column name and its data type. I have multiple columns and want to change all in one query along with their datatype.

**What i tried**

1. Changing column type then renaming it.

```
ALTER TABLE customers  ALTER COLUMN phone TYPE numeric 
RENAME COLUMN phone TO contact_phone
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE customers  ALTER COLUMN phone TYPE numeric,
RENAME COLUMN phone TO contact_phone
```

2. Changing multiple column type then renaming it.

```
ALTER TABLE customers  
  ALTER COLUMN phone TYPE numeric, 
  ALTER COLUMN address TYPE text, 
  RENAME COLUMN phone TO contact_phone,
  RENAME COLUMN address TO contact_address
```

3. Tried to change all column data type then rename it

```
ALTER TABLE customers  
ALTER COLUMN phone TYPE numeric,ALTER COLUMN address TYPE text
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE customers 
 RENAME COLUMN phone TO contact_phone,RENAME COLUMN address TO contact_address
```

**Issue:**
Each time I am getting an error in the `RENAME` clause which is 
**SQL State : 42601**

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can change the data type of several columns in one `ALTER TABLE` statement, renaming a column can only be done one at a time. So you will have to use several `ALTER TABLE` statements.

I would recommend to run all statements in a single transaction, that way you have to acquire the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock only once.

Comment: i tried this as well .. used two alter statements in first i changed datatypes and in second i renamed columns. but got issue in renaming. kindly look at third point in my question under **what i tried** heading

Comment: I see. I have adapted the answer.

Comment: i just tried in editor instead of query and i noticed i am getting error in renaming multiple column in one query.
ALTER TABLE customers 
 RENAME COLUMN phone TO contact_phone,RENAME COLUMN address TO contact_address
RENAME multiple time is not acceptable by editor i think.
i tried without  putting comma before next RENAME clause still issue.

Comment: And according to this documentation http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rename-column/
 we can rename multiple columns in one statement
but when i tried i got error

Comment: The tutorial is plain wrong. Look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) instead.

Comment: There is not any example to rename multiple columns in this documentation

Comment: Exactly! If you look at the syntax diagram for `RENAME` (of a column), you will see that there are no provisions for more than one such clause.